# A descending chain and choice axiom.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> Let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$ such that for every $x\in A$ there exist a element $y\in A$ such that $x\mathrel{R}y$ the there exist a function $f\colon\omega\rightarrow A$ such that $f(n^+)Rf(n)$.

I would like some hint to this exercise using axiom of choice.

Thanks!

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ used for? What's $f$?

Comment: Oups, it was a very big mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Fix a choice function $G$ on non-empty subsets of $A$, and some $x_0$ in $A$, and by induction define $f(0)=x_0$, and $f(n+1)$ to be a chosen element from the relevant set of witnesses.

Comment: Defining $B_x=\{y:y R x\}$ and $F:A\rightarrow A$ as $F(a)=G(B_a)$ then we can assure than there exist a function $f$ such that $f(0)=x_0$ and $f(n^+)=F(f(n))$. This is the function require. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.